# EditText Keyboard is dissappearing

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in LinearLayout. When clicked to button, I am removing all views in layout and adding another view. When back button is pressed I am removing all views and adding editText and Button again. Now when I touch on editText, keyboard does not become visible! I think maybe it is a focus issue. How can handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it will work for you.

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  if(m != null){
      m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Actually I was trying  `m.toggleSoftInput(0,0);` Anyway, there is another problem now. Next button on keyboard is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

show keyboard using

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: ok but make the editText focusable and clickable and then it should work without this code. maybe your view is not clickable and it won't enter in onClick event

Comment: No no. It is clickable and focusable. And I debug, there is not any problem about events..